# Access Docker API on Windows via Named Pipes

Tags: c#, windows, docker, named-pipes

According to the Docker for Windows [FAQ](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#how-do-i-connect-to-the-remote-docker-engine-api), " clients can connect to the Docker Engine through a named pipe: npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"

I have been trying to connect to the API via named pipes to no avail:

```
public class DockerNamedPipeTest
{
    private const string PIPE_PATH = "docker_engine";

    public void Test()
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = 
            new NamedPipeClientStream(
                ".", 
                PIPE_PATH, 
                PipeDirection.InOut, 
                PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 
                TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation))
        {
            pipeClient.Connect(30);                
            Send(pipeClient);
            Receive(pipeClient);
        }
    }

    public void Send(NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient)
    {
        if (pipeClient.IsConnected)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GET /containers/json");
            pipeClient.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            pipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
            pipeClient.Flush();
        }
    }

    public void Receive(NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        if (pipeClient.IsConnected && pipeClient.CanRead)
        {
            do
            {                    
                byte b = (byte)pipeClient.ReadByte();   //  <-- Hangs here
                result += Convert.ToChar(b).ToString();
            }
            while (!pipeClient.IsMessageComplete);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It's been a long time since I touched named pipes, but after skimming over some documentation like [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365783(v=vs.85).aspx), have you tried specifying the pipe path like `\\./pipe/docker_engine`, or using the full URI given in the docs you linked (`npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine`)?

Comment: It throws a timeout exception if I use those. Using just docker_engine and it connects. Also, running sysinternals tool pipelist shows the correct pipe name is docker_engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the answer can be found inside the source of the Docker.DotNet code, specifically in the DockerPipeStream.cs class in the method called `CloseWrite()`:

(https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet/blob/master/src/Docker.DotNet/DockerPipeStream.cs)

```
// The Docker daemon expects a write of zero bytes to signal the end of writes. Use native
// calls to achieve this since CoreCLR ignores a zero-byte write.
```

I adapted this method to my code and the code no longer hangs.

I now get a **400 Bad Request** but at least now I know why the communication with the docker daemon was hanging. It would have been nice if the Docker for Windows FAQ had mentioned this nuance.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's [.NET client library for Docker](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet) supports named pipes, have you looked at that?

Here's an example:

```
using Docker.DotNet;
DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine"))
 .CreateClient();
```